# French characters in IE11 markup not being passed correctly to scripts

Tags: jquery, character-encoding, internationalization, internet-explorer-11

I have a page that uses some data attributes on links that are passed to a jquery load method.  They work fine in english and on chrome/firefox/edge, but in IE11 in French only the special characters in the data-alias do not get passed to my php processor correctly.
this alis:

```
alias  = 2019-apr-domain-annonce-ses-résultats-pour-le-premier-trimestre-de-2019
```

gets sent to the php connector as:

```
[alias] => 2019-apr-domain-annonce-ses-r▒sultats-pour-le-premier-trimestre-de-2019
```

The script works for every other browser IE11 is just not passing the FR charaters correctly:

```
$('.no-link').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var alias = $(this).data('alias');
        var resource = $(this).data('resource');
        var panels = $('.tab-pane'), i;
        var pdf = $(this).data('pdf');
        if(pdf.length > 0){
            window.open(pdf, '_blank'); 
        }else{
            $( "#article > span" ).load( "/insightsconnector/?resource="+resource+"&alias="+alias, function( response, status, xhr ) {
                console.log('loading article');
            });
        }
    })
```

Example of HTML element:

```
<a 
href="a-propos-de-nous/nouvelles/2019/2019-apr-domain-annonce-ses-résultats-pour-le-premier-trimestre-de-2019/" 
class="article hero-article no-link full-box idx1" 
data-alias="2019-apr-domain-annonce-ses-résultats-pour-le-premier-trimestre-de-2019" 
data-pdf="" 
data-resource="75348699262731">
    ....
</a>
```

The aliases are built by a CMS system from the actual resource's title so 'stripping' out weird characters is not a solution.

What is the correct way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the character set in the HTTP headers, make sure you have provided the character set, like this:

```
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

If still not working, please try to use one of the following methods:

- Disable the Auto-Select setting in Internet Explorer.
- Provide the character set in the HTTP headers.
- Move the META tag to within the first kilobyte of data that is parsed by MSHTML.  Although we do not know how much data the parser reads at a time, this location will resolve the issue.
- Increase the size of the server's initial HTTP response. The initial size should be at least 1 KB.
- Make sure that the System Locale setting matches the character set of the META tag that is specified in the HTML page.

Reference [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928847/internet-explorer-uses-the-wrong-character-set-when-it-renders-an-html).